# If I start walking on the border of a bounded domain, will I end up where I started?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

If I am on the border of a bounded domain with continuous border (or maybe a manifold?) and I start moving in some direction, will I eventually end up where I started?

And if so, will I eventually reach the point where I started moving in the starting direction?

Comment: If you walk round the world are you guaranteed you'll end up where you started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. To see this first we note that if we continuously rotate points on a circle by some irrational multiple of $2\pi$ that no matter how many times we do it we will never return any point to its starting location. Now extrude the circle into a cylinder and glue the ends together to form a torus. Choose a point on the circles that were glued together and a direction that would wind around the cylinder so the path ends at a point which is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$ away from the starting location on the circle. This straight path will never reach its initial location.

Comment: Thank you very much :)